# Structure of group of symmetries of a napkin-ring.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, intuition, symmetry

Trying to get a better understanding of [dicyclic groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dicyclic_group), I wonder what the structure of symmetries of a napkin-ring is.

Suppose you paint a pattern on the ring that has $n$-fold rotational symmetry and also up-down and left-righ symmetry, like $n$ periods of a sine wave that runs around the ring.  Then the rotational symmetry is generated by an element $a$ of order $n$, where $n=26$ in the following depictions using the uppercase letters $\text{A⋅⋅⋅Z}$:
$\def\pp#1{{\style{display: inline-block; transform:scale(+1,+1)}{\text{#1}}}}$
$\def\np#1{{\style{display: inline-block; transform:scale(-1,+1)}{\text{#1}}}}$
$\def\pn#1{{\style{display: inline-block; transform:scale(+1,-1)}{\text{#1}}}}$
$\def\nn#1{{\style{display: inline-block; transform:scale(-1,-1)}{\text{#1}}}}$

Then $a^k$ generates the 26 pure rotations, and $\{a^k\}\simeq \Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$:

$$\pp{ABC···XYZ}\\ \pp{BCD···YZA}\\ \vdots\\ \pp{ZAB···WXY}\tag{00}$$

Adding an element $x$ of order 2 turns the group into the dihedral group $D_{2n}$, where $x$ in the depiction is turning the ring upside down: $a^kx$ generates

$$\nn{ABC···XYZ}\\ \nn{BCD···YZA}\\ \vdots\\ \nn{ZAB···WXY}\tag{10}$$

We can add yet another element $y$ of order 2, like the action of a vertical mirror.  In two dimensions and with a flat $n$-gon, we'd have $y=a^mx$ for some $m$, but in 3D with the ring this is not the case, and we get $2n$ more symmetries: $a^ky$ are the mirror images of $a^k$:

$$\np{ABC···XYZ}\\ \np{BCD···YZA}\\ \vdots\\ \np{ZAB···WXY}\tag{01}$$

and $a^kxy$ are the mirror images of $a^kx$ resp. upside-down reflections of $a^k$:

$$\pn{ABC···XYZ}\\ \pn{BCD···YZA}\\ \vdots\\ \pn{ZAB···WXY}\tag{11}$$

So what's the group structure of these symmetries $S$?  As far as I understand, we have

$$
\langle a,x\rangle \simeq \langle a,y\rangle
\simeq \langle a,xy\rangle
\simeq \langle a,yx\rangle \simeq D_{2n} \tag 2
$$

and that $S \not\simeq D_{4n}$ and $S \not\simeq Q_{4n}$
for $n$ not too small, and where $Q_{4n}$ denotes the dicyclic group of order $4n$.
That $S\not\simeq Q_{4n}$ I infer from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4088321/746312) that states that dicyclic groups are *"not easy to visualize"*.  And for $Q_{4n}$ we'd need an element $z\neq a^k$ of order 4, which we don't have.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your ring and sine wave, but in your example with the alphabet, $xy$ commutes with $a$ no?  (In fact, it's not possible for all 3 involutions to invert $a$. If $x$ and $y$ invert $a$ by conjugation, then $xy$ must centralise it.)

Comment: @verret: I think yes.  nI eq (11), the plane of the mirror is parallel to the plane in which $a$ rotates the letters.  Does this mean eq (2) is wrong in stating that $\langle a,xy \rangle$ is $D_{2n}$?

Comment: Yes, $\langle a,xy\rangle$ will be abelian, in fact a direct product $\langle a\rangle\times\langle xy\rangle$ (which is cyclic in the case that $a$ has odd order). Moreover, $S$ will also be a direct product $S=\langle a,x\rangle\times\langle xy\rangle\cong D_{2n}\times C_2$. (Which, again, is actually dihedral if $a$ has odd order.)